# How to check if an ALAsset still exists using a URL

Tags: iphone, alasset, alassetslibrary

I've got an array containing ALAsset urls (not full ALAsset objects)
So each time I start my application I want to check my array to see if it's still up to date...

So I tried

```
NSData *assetData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=1000000001&ext=PNG"];
```

but assetData is allways nil

thx for the help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock: method of ALAssetsLibrary instead to get the asset from its URL.

```
// Create assets library
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];

// Try to load asset at mediaURL
[library assetForURL:mediaURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
    // If asset exists
    if (asset) {
        // Type your code here for successful
    } else {
        // Type your code here for not existing asset
    }
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    // Type your code here for failure (when user doesn't allow location in your app)
}];
```

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to do ? These blocks are called asynchronously, so instead of returning a value, you should instead put the code which need the asset in a method and call this method in the block or you can put the code directly in the block.

Comment: I want to loop on my array of assetUrl to check if the asset still exists and if not I want to remove it from the list and delete cached files

Comment: your solution looks fine but I get this error  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFArray: 0x190300> was mutated while being enumerated.

Comment: It's because you modify an array in a enumerate loop, instead of modify the array, create another mutable array, add all asset which are available and use this array instead

Comment: I am sending the same URL over and over again and always tells me not exist.

Comment: ALAssetLibrary will change all its ALAsset's url , if any insertion or deletion occur. its damn hell.. and we cannot believe ALAsset's url

Answer (score 7):

Having assets path you can use this function to check if image exist:

```
-(BOOL) imageExistAtPath:(NSString *)assetsPath
{  
    __block BOOL imageExist = NO; 
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library assetForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:assetsPath] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        if (asset) {
            imageExist = YES;
            }
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
    }];
    return imageExist;
}
```

Remember that checking if image exist is checking asynchronyus.
If you want to wait until new thread finish his life call function "imageExistAtPath" in main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self imageExistAtPath:assetPath];
});
```

Or you can use semaphores, but this is not very nice solution:

```
-(BOOL) imageExistAtPath:(NSString *)assetsPath
{  
    __block BOOL imageExist = YES; 
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);   
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);   
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{  
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library assetForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:assetsPath] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
            if (asset) {
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore); 
            } else {
                imageExist = NO;
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore); 
                }
        } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
        }];
    });
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); 
    return imageExist;
}
```

Comment: For those stumbling on this one, I believe it's actually incorrect. As you point out, `assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock`: invokes the blocks asynchronously, so it will most probably reach the `return imageExist` before the resultBlock has been invoked, and imageExist is most certainly always NO.

Answer (score 5):

For iOS 8 or later, there is a synchronous method to check if an `ALAsset` exists.

```
@import Photos;

if ([PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[assetURL] options:nil].count) {
    // exist
}
```

Swift:

```
import Photos

if PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([assetURL], options: nil).count > 0 {
   // exist
}
```

Swift 3:

```
import Photos

if PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [assetURL], options: nil).count > 0 {
   // exist
}
```

Comment: this help me to check whether the image exists in photo library or not. I would like to share the Swift 2.0 version code below.                                          if (PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([imageURL], options:nil).count != 0)

Comment: Will This Solution Work for Video Assets too ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to check if file exists

```
NSURL *yourFile = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourFileHere.txt"];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:storeFile.path 
isDirectory:NO]) {

    NSLog(@"The file DOES exist");

} else {

    NSLog(@"The file does NOT exist");
}
```